# Create swipe to reveal buttons for iOS 7, using clear color for background

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I followed this tutorial http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/reproducing-the-ios-7-mail-apps-interface/ to add more button beside delete button when swiping.

But the problem is the cell need to use clear color so the background image can be seen. But that approach used scrollview to display the content view and the buttons view of tableview cell. If the content view of the scrollview has any background color instead of clear color, it can hide the buttons so these buttons only display a part determined by our finger when swiping on the cell, using clear color for background makes these buttons show without the need to swipe from right to left on the cell.

So anyone can give me a suggestion to use the clear color to display the background image without revealing the under buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **MGSwipeTableCell** class for creating swipeable buttons with any colour you need. It will not interfere with the tableview cell color as well. It is very easy and quick to implement.

https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell

Comment: Thanks but my project manager does not want to use a library for this function. Any idea to handle it manually?